# How to Share Code between Blazor Server, and .net Maui App

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, maui, .net-maui

I have watched the Demo by Dan Roth about using a Shared Code Base between a Blazor App, and a Mobile App.  It looks cool.

So now I will try to implement this. What I currently have is a .net 6 Blazor Server App which is used by Customers to access account information.  This works great.

But now I want to expose this as a Mobile App.  So how do I convert this app to a .Net Maui Hybrid App?  The goal is to re-use the existing code that is already written with as few changes as possible.

I have tried creating the sample .net Maui Blazor sample.  It builds and runs as a Desktop app, and it uses Blazor code.  But it runs as a native app, not a web app.  So how to also run it as a Web App?

I have read the [Maui Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/maui?view=aspnetcore-6.0) intro, but it does not show how to use it as a Web App.

This [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/62) implies that it is currently not supported.

Am I missing something?

Comment: A Maui Blazor app cannot be a web app. The part that you share is the Blazor code. First write a Blazor app (no Maui) for Server or Browser, Then add that Blazor code to an app.

Comment: Have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCR26PkaHmk It helped me understand how to break my blazor application into razor libraries to be shared across different implementations.

Comment: Be careful about making a webview, because Apple refuses to release iOS apps that only utilise a webview. You can read about it here: https://qr.ae/prewsN

Comment: Maybe this could help someone: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_C8X-b2qXE&ab_channel=DanielHindrikes

Answer (score 1):

Different concepts there:

**Blazor Webassembly** - a precompiled binary executable ran inside someones browser , which can talk to a server via a webapi or whatever else you need.

**Blazor Server** - Serverside web application which feeds data back and fore with client via signal-r

**Maui** - a development framework for building cross-platform native applications

However, one feature of Maui is a blazorwebview - so what that allows you to do is embed a BlazorWebassembly Webview - along with a blazor webassembly  app in a crossplatform native (I guess technically hybrid) application. In that scenario you can share webassembly components in the form of Razor components (and dataclients/business objects etc) between a webassembly project and a maui project with a blazor webassembly webview - infact they have template to do exactly that.

What you could also do, is have a Maui app, with just a webview control, pointing at webserver which is hosting a blazor server app - essentially creating a hybrid app (ie a webview on the client), but that seems to miss the point somewhat.